# Export data from table to excel, how to stop excel from auto converting the value?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, export-to-excel

I am currently working on an export function on a project. (I am a fresh graduated student)

I had successfully done the function. the issue I facing now is the excel will auto convert(or format?) my initial value to another form. May I know is there any solution to stop from excel perform auto-converting to a value?

> scenario: original number is 7778362019198430, after export, it shows 
>              7.77836E+15

### here is the code of my export function

```
function fnExcelReport(tableID) {

            var downloadLink;
            var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
            var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

            // Specify file name
            var d = new Date();
            var todaysDate = d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getMonth() + '-' + 
                d.getDate();
            filename = 'CashCard_' + todaysDate + '.xls';

            // Create download link element
            downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

            if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
                var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
                    type: dataType
                });
                navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
            }else{
                // Create a link to the file
                downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

                // Setting the file name
                downloadLink.download = filename;

                //triggering the function
                downloadLink.click();
            }

        }
```

The expected output should be as same as what the original value which is 7778362019198430,but excel perform auto converting, the output after export will auto convert to  7.77836E+15.

Is there any way to stop it? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The number in this format "7.77836E+15" is called scientific notation, it represents 7.77836 × 10<sup>15</sup>.

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/452832/turn-off-scientific-notation-in-excel) StackExchange thread says that if you right-click the cells and click "Format cells" and choose "Number" you can stop Excel from using scientific notation.

It looks like there is a lot to your code that we cannot see, but I suspect you will be able to format cells when creating the document.

You might want to try this.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. i know that i can just reformat the output in excel file manually. I am seeking a solution stop exel from convert the original value to scientific notation based. i want it always display the original value automatically. is there any solution ? Very appreciated your reply by the way.

Comment: We cannot see your code where you generate your excel spreadsheet so we do not know how you are doing it so we cannot provide you with that answer, try looking up the documentation for whatever approach you are using whether it be a plugin or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this in javascript. If you move your export functionality to c# this can done with setting the Cell Style like

```
sheet.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("style", "textmode");
```